# Wrong version of question showing up (or some info at the profile page)?

Tags: support, status-norepro, comments, help-center

Is this a bug?

See the comments under [Way to set a label leader line length (not using annotation) in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260708), i.e. comment from @kahukowhai and my (Abc1) reply to that.

so basically as the comments have been deleted in the meantime (maybe with higher reputation some can see), what happened was that kahukowhai was saying not to use irrelevant tags, but actually that tag has been deleted more than 3 hours before kahukowhai posted the comment because the question has been devided into 2 ...is that possible that @kahukowhai saw a wrong version of the question or what happened?

I also found more times things like - at my profile showing older v. of Q/A title, deleted Q or showing me I was given some badges or reputation points and after few minutes it was showing like as it was not true (and out of any info that I found in my profile nothing would indicate that I e.g. lost some reput.points in the meantime); that makes it look a little confused
...loging out and in, refreshing, restarting broser and pc - none of that changed that, so I was wondering if that all are somehow connected?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this came about by caching on the device used by @kahukowhai but that is not something that I can be certain of.  It may also have been that the user read your original question earlier and only got around to commenting on it much later without re-reading.

I agree that the sequence/timing of that comment seems odd, but I don't think there is value in trying to track down exactly what happened in this instance because the tools do not make it easy to do.

So that other users are not confused about the comments you mention, which I think were deleted just before you asked this question, I am showing a screenshot of all comments on that question below.

[image]

Comment: ok, I just found more times things like - at my profile showing older v. of Q/A title, deleted Q or showing me I was given some badges or reputation points and after few minutes it was showing like as it was not true (and out of any info that I found in my profile nothing would indicate that I e.g. lost some reput.points in the meantime)...loging out and in, refreshing, restarting broser and pc - none of that changed that, so I was wondering if that all are somehow connected (and maybe even with the thing mentioned with comments)?

Comment: @Abc1 that sounds bizarre but without specific examples and something reproducible I'm not keen to start investigating any of those issues.